# Linked-List remove after method java

Tags: java, algorithm, linked-list

ive been working on a linked list and Im trying to remove a node after another node. Ive got how to remove before the current node but i now need the after and I cant seem to figure it out. I got it to work once but it removed every node after the current not just the one next to the current. Here is the code for inserting after and removing before:

```
// Remove the node containing item nVal
public void removeBefore(E curVal, E nVal) {
    // You implement this method for Assignment 2
    Node<E> newNode = new Node<E>(nVal);

    Node<E> curr = head;
    Node<E> prev = null;

    if (head.getNodeValue() == curVal) {
        newNode.setNext(head);
        head = newNode;
        return;
    }

    // scan until locate node or come to end of list
    while (curr != null) {
        // have a match 
        if (curr.getNodeValue() == curVal) {

            newNode.setNext(curr);
            prev.setNext(newNode);
            break;
        } else {
            // advanced curr and prev
            prev = null;
            curr = curr.getNext();
        }
    }
}


// Insert new node nVal to the list after current node curVal 
public void insertNodeAfter(E nVal, E curVal) {
    // You implement this method for Week 11 tutorial
    Node<E> newNode = new Node<E>(nVal);

    Node<E> curr = head;

    // scan until locate node or come to end of list
    while (curr != null) {
        // have a match 
        // Replaced == with .equals
        if (curr.getNodeValue().equals(curVal)) {
            // insert node
            newNode.setNext(curr.getNext());
            curr.setNext(newNode);
            break;
        } else {
            curr = curr.getNext();
        }
    }
}
```

Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: Is this for Assignment 3? If so, solving it by yourself will help you a lot in learning java/data structures and give you more satisfaction than having it solved by someone else.

Comment: "I got it to work once but it removed every node after the current not just the one next to the current" Where's that code?

Comment: Please add code for removing after as well and explain where is the problem

Comment: @vefthym It is related to school work but at another school and ive worked on other parts enough and i just need to know where i should be looking for this.

Comment: @weston I had the code but after trying to fix it i ended up creating an endless loop and i lose the code in the crash.

Comment: @Sanjeev Ive been trying to base the remove after code on the insertAfter method i have. I based my removebefore method on my insert before method so i thought the insertAfter() method would be what i should base my removeAfter as well.

Comment: @Pat inserting and item before/after another item makes sense but deleting an item before/after another item does not make sense. deleting means an existing item needs to be deleted wherever it is placed in list. Am i missing something here?

Comment: All this is bad :-( : The shown method `removeBefore` is in fact an insertion method. And in a linked list, you normally do not remove after or before, but just remove the current node (in you case the node containing a given value)

Comment: `insertBefore`: instead `prev = null;` you probably meant `prev = curr;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code for removing an item containing a given in a singly linked list consists in :

- search the list from the head for the value, keeping track of previous node
- if the node is first (previous is null) start the list at next
- else, make previous point directly to next (also works for last node)

Code could be something like:

```
// Remove the node containing item nVal
public void remove(E curVal) {
    Node<E> curr = head;
    Node<E> prev = null;


    // scan until locate node or come to end of list
    while (curr != null) {
        // have a match 
        if (curr.getNodeValue().equals(curVal)) {

            if (prev == null) {  // curr is first node: just start to next
                head = curr.getNext();
            }
            else {   // make prev point to next
                prev.setNext(curr.getNext());
            }
            break;
        } else {
            // advanced curr and prev
            prev = curr;
            curr = curr.getNext();
        }
    }
}
```